# Does triply transitive mean there are three orbits?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a group action is transitive, it possesses a single orbit. Does that mean a group action that is doubly transitive has two orbits, and so on?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroupAction.html

Comment: Doubly transitive actions are transitive, so ...

Comment: It might be more interesting to assume that the action of $G$ on $X$ is $n$-transitive and try to count the number of orbits of the induced action of $G$ on $X^n$.

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Doubly_transitive_group_action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Multiple transitivity is more restrictive than single transitivity, rather than a broader concept. If we can send three arbitrary elements to three elements we choose, we can certainly send a single element anywhere we want it to go.

There are significant restrictions on the form of multiply transitive groups as a result - and some of the special ones (eg Matthieu Groups) are at the heart of the 26 exceptional simple groups.